# Find the position of the React component in HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

Elements are created and attached in the table, I want to find the position of a particular element,
I have used UseRef hook,

`const inputRef = useRef(null);`

**dynamic creation looks like**

```
    return (
      <td style={{ margin: "1rem", padding: "1rem" }}>
        <Datetime
          ref={inputRef}
          closeOnSelect={true}
          dateFormat="MMM yy"
          timeFormat={false}
        />
      </td>
    );
  }
```

**in UseEffect hook looks like**

I tried both OffsetTop and getBoundingClientRect.  both didnt help

```
    console.log(inputRef); //here no offsetTop is no there in current
    //console.log(inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect());
  }, []);
```

outPut Looks as below in console.

```
{current: n}
current: n
props: Object
context: Object
refs: Object
updater: Object
_renderCalendar: ƒ () {}
_showView: ƒ () {}
viewToMethod: Object
nextView: Object
_updateDate: ƒ () {}
_viewNavigate: ƒ () {}
_setTime: ƒ () {}
_openCalendar: ƒ () {}
_closeCalendar: ƒ () {}
_handleClickOutside: ƒ () {}
_onInputFocus: ƒ () {}
_onInputChange: ƒ () {}
_onInputKeyDown: ƒ () {}
_onInputClick: ƒ () {}
state: Object
_reactInternals: FiberNode
_reactInternalInstance: Object
isReactComponent: Object
setState: ƒ () {}
forceUpdate: ƒ () {}
<constructor>: "n"
```

how to get the position of the current ref element

my code in the sandbox :

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#test {
  top: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Just another Div </div> <!-- Remove this to see the value change !-->
<div>Just another Div </div> <!-- Remove this to see the value change !-->
<span>Just another Span </span> <!-- Remove this to see the value change !-->

<div id="test">
  <p>Click the button to get offsetTop for the test div.</p>
  <p><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button></p>
  <p>offsetTop is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDiv.offsetTop;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this: `offsetTop` works everytime.

Edit:

For a list, you can add an index/counter, to the ID of elements, and then it becomes easier to get ref from the DOM.
[Sandbox Link for React Demo](http://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wescoff-tet2e?file=/src/components/list.jsx)

Comment: but the problem is when you are adding a component into another component based on the list returned, creating the element with the id is not possible so, we don't have that Element id,
even when we hardcode the id then the same id will be there for all element created in that loop.
how to find the position of the element for such elements in React

Comment: I have added a demo in which i am traversing through a list and also adding a unique ID to everyone. This should work in your case too.
You can create a sandbox for just your code if you're still getting stuck to get ref from the list. That way, I can tell you the the solution specific to your code

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score -1):

You can get reference with id and then can apply getBoundingClientRect()

here is your code

```
import Datetime from "react-datetime";
import "./styles.css";
import "react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let table = [];
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    let a = document.getElementById('input');
    console.log("answer",a.getBoundingClientRect()); //here no offsetTop is no there in current
    //console.log(inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect());
  });
  function getRow() {
    return (
      <td style={{ margin: "1rem", padding: "1rem" }}>
        <div id="input">
        <Datetime
          ref={inputRef}
          closeOnSelect={true}
          dateFormat="MMM yy"
          timeFormat={false}
        />
        </div>.
      </td>
    );
  }
  function getRows() {
    let row = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
      row.push(getRow());
    }
    return <tr>{row}</tr>;
  }

  function getTable() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
      table.push(getRows());
    }
    return table;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table style={{ border: "solid 1px blue" }}>
        <tbody>{getTable()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: that won't help me, let's say I want to know the position of DateTime picker which I clicked, now all the element will have the same ID `input`.
how to diff which DateTime Picker is clicked and find the position of a particular element?